Save gz::rendering::ScenePtr as an SDF file
I have created a scene using gazebo c++ API. The scene is similar to the one showcased in gz-sensors save_image example.
Now, I want to save the scene as an SDF file. Is there an API for it? If not, what options do I have?

No, I don't think there's an API for converting a gz-rendering scene into an SDF file. There's an example that converts a Gazebo world into a Collada (.dae) file. Perhaps you can get some inspiration from that for getting the underlying meshes of all of you gz-rendering objects, add them to a common::Mesh object and export them to a Collada file.
